# How to remove ui bootstrap datepicker footer angularjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

**Note :** You can find answer in this article : [Remove footer from angular ui bootstrap date picker](http://www.coding-issues.com/2015/10/how-to-remove-angular-ui-bootstrap-date-picker-footer.html)

I am using ui-bootstrap datapicket for date of birth field. as below

```
<input type="text" data-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" data-show-weeks="false" data-ng-model="model.dateOfBirth" id="dateOfbirth" name="dateOfBirth">
```

It is working fine. as shown below

[image]

So my question is how can i hide the footer of the date picker ??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do it globally, like the following:

```
myApp.config(function (datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig) {
    // datepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
    // datepickerPopupConfig.toggleWeeksText = null;
    datepickerPopupConfig.showButtonBar = false;
});
```

Or you can do it for a specific instance of date-picker, like the folling:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dt" show-button-bar="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for specific calendar hide button bar. You saved my time :-)

Comment: for newer version of ui bootstrap, inject in uibDatepickerPopupConfig

Answer (score 6):

Looking for the same, I've found this answer:

[Remove week column and button from Angular-ui bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678009/remove-week-column-and-button-from-angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker)

So:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(function (datepickerConfig) {
      datepickerPopupConfig.showButtonBar = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The template for the directive is included in the JS if you download the - "ui-bootstrap-tpls-[version].min.js" file.

It might be hard to modify the minified version so you may want to check out the unminified version.

But basically you're looking for the HTML code found @ https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/datepicker/popup.html

Once you find that bit in your JS file, modify it as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Its quietly a **bad solution** for that, but i did not saw a possible soltion [in the documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).
You can maybe hide them with CSS in this way:

`[ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl"] > hr ~ button { display:none }`

When you also want to hide the `<hr>`:

`[ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl"] > hr { display:none }`

Replace **DatepickerDemoCtrl** with your controller.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the solution. Using CSS we can hide it. But am searching is there any attribute like show-footer="false". but there is no such attribute mentioned in docs. :-(. so CSS is the only way to hide it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very simple. You can modify the datepickerPopupWrap directive in the angular bootstrap module. 
You can find a templateUrl field. Something like this

templateUrl:template/datepicker/popup.html,

Just replace that field with 
template:

```
        ^<ul class=\^dropdown-menu\^ ng-style=\^{display: (isOpen && 'block') || 'none', top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}\^ class=\^dropdown-menu\^>\n^ +
        ^   <li ng-transclude></li>\n^ +
        ^</ul>^,
```

NOTE: Replace ^ with " . Since stackoverflow takes it as a blockquote i used ^.

---

template field defines how to display the output in the browser. You can even include your own elements and modify as you wish.

Comment: i am getting some syntax error: Error: Template must have exactly one root element. was: ^<ul class=^dropdown-menu^ ng-style=^{display: (isOpen && 'block') || 'none', top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}^ class=^dropdown-menu^>
^ +        ^   <li ng-transclude></li>
^ +        ^</ul>^