# Remove week column and button from Angular-ui bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [angular-ui bootstrap datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). Now I need to remove #(week) column and week button from datepicker. This date picker is being used in many forms of my application. I want to remove week column from all of them.

For this, I had globally configured the datepickerConfig (show-weeks) but still it is not working. Can anyone please let me know I am doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please, look at this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6i4G7JkvBiWXZYlrV2GL?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(function (datepickerConfig) {
      datepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks It's working. Do you know how to hide only weeks button from bottom?

Comment: I looked at source for datepickerPopup, there is no possible way for doing this.
You can use dirty hack and hide button with css instead, something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/6i4G7JkvBiWXZYlrV2GL?p=preview ... but it's a very dirty hack %)

Comment: Thanks, It's okay for me.

Answer (score 12):

For datepicker in popup, datepicker-options  attribute has value dateOptions in which json can be added for any datepicker settings as shown in the HTML below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" **datepicker-options="dateOptions"** date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

In javascript this is given

```
 $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1,
    
  };
```

just add showWeeks:false in dateOptions like this,

```
 $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1,
    showWeeks:false
  };
```

or you can add like this 'show-weeks':'false' .
Demo is shown at plunker  [http://plnkr.co/edit/qbp3IObj13op2RS17IEg?p=preview][1]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it only removes the weeks from this datepicker, not all datepickers in the application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I think it's a cleaner solution than the accepted answer however showWeeks:'false' wouldn't work for me. I had to remove the single quotes and then it worked.

Comment: Angular 1.5.6 I also had to remove the single quotes for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for help, however without single quotes solution is work.
Thus, showWeeks:false is work in place of showWeeks:'false'.

Answer (score 4):

If angular bootstrap ui version is 0.14.3, use the following

```
app.config(function (uibDatepickerConfig) {
    uibDatepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
    uibDatepickerConfig.showButtonBar = false;
});
```

Comment: showButtonBar is set in the PopupConfig:
uibDatepickerPopupConfig.showButtonBar = false;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it directly in the template, simply add the following attribute to the input:`show-weeks="false"`.

Comment: I've been trying to use the show-weeks attribute and it doesn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: Well, I have it working at work but I can't reproduce in the demo plunker of documentation. It does work with the inline calendar but does't work for the popup. It might be linked with this issue:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1132

I'll check on Monday my code to see how I did it.

Comment: THIS would only work if you are using directive as an element such as <datepicker show-weeks='false' /> if you are using <input , that attribute will not be read.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the weeks number you can use two different way.

First one: adding into controller

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1   };
```

or Second way: add attribute in input field

```
show-weeks="'false'"
```

Comment: THIS would only work if you are using directive as an element such as <datepicker show-weeks='false' /> if you are using <input , that attribute will not be read.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" [bsConfig]="{showWeekNumbers:false}" />
```

or

```
<datepicker show-weeks='false' />
```